# Getting different encryption results between C#.Net and Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, character-encoding, cryptography, hash

I want to encrypt some strings based on SHA1 algorithm in both C#.Net and Oracle 10g.

**My algorithm in C#.Net:**

```
string salt = "123";
System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1 sha = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1.Create();
byte[] preHash = System.Text.Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(salt);
byte[] hash = sha.ComputeHash(preHash);

string password = System.Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
password = password.Substring(0, 8);

// password value is: "7yP7/lkJ"
```

**In Oracle:**

```sql
Create Or Replace Function Sha1(P_Value Varchar2,P_Length Number) Return Varchar2 
Is 
P_String Varchar2(2000) := P_Value ;
L_Hash_Value_Raw    Raw (100);    
Lv_Hash_Value_Varchar   Varchar2 (40); 
Begin   
    L_Hash_Value_Raw := Dbms_Crypto.Hash (Src   => Utl_Raw.Cast_To_Raw(P_String),       
                                         Typ   => Dbms_Crypto.Hash_Sh1);   
-- Convert Into Varchar2 
Select   Utl_Raw.Cast_To_Varchar2(Utl_Encode.Base64_Encode(L_Hash_Value_Raw))
Into   Lv_Hash_Value_Varchar  
From   Dual;  
    Lv_Hash_Value_Varchar := Substr(Lv_Hash_Value_Varchar,0,P_Length);
Return Lv_Hash_Value_Varchar;
End;
```

---

**Oracle's invokation:**

```
select SHA1('123', 8) from dual; -- Result: "QLOAFWMI"
```

Maybe my general question is what is the difference between Oracle (PL/SQL) and .Net regarding encryption/raw/hex levels? I guess that answer would solve this specific problem.

Comment: Just so you know, there is a difference between encyption and hashing. SHA1 is a *hashing* algorithm.

Comment: LordCover, could you try Alexey's answer before we take another look at the problem?

Comment: Damn, you're the third person today that hashed passwords with single iteration hash functions. Don't do that. And why would you do password hashing on the db server?

Comment: @CodeInChaos My secret key is `DateTime.Today`, My salt is different per each client (unique value for each one of them), so it is no problem to hash passwords with single iteration since they can't know what we are encrypting in the first place.

Comment: @owlstead replied to Alexey's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you use wrong encoding. try the following code:

```
string salt = "123";
System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1 sha = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1.Create();
byte[] preHash = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(salt);
byte[] hash = sha.ComputeHash(preHash);

string password = System.Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
password = password.Substring(0, 8);
```

Comment: I tried this, `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes` in C#, and `UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW (string, 'AL32UTF8');` in Oracle, result are different from before but still different from each other, and none of the 4 results (C# before, Oracle before, C# after, Oracle after) match any other one.

Comment: you don't need to change sql code. results are the same if you use my C# code and your sql code. they return "QLOAFWMI"

Comment: Thanks, it worked but the output password 3rd letter is `0` not `O` in both algorithms.