# Small query for logging in users with salted password

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have codeigniter model like this

```
<?php

class Model_Login extends CI_Model{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function login_submit($arrayData){
        extract($arrayData);
        $username=clean($txtusername);
        $password=clean($txtpassword);

        //first get salt for the respective user.
        $getsalt=$this->db->query("SELECT PASSWORD_SALT FROM USER_INFOS WHERE USER_NNAME=?",array($username))->row();
        $salt=$getsalt->PASSWORD_SALT;
        $password=sha1($salt.$password);

        $query=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM USER_INFOS WHERE STATUS='Y' AND USER_NNAME=? AND USER_PASSWORD=?",array($username,$password));

        if($query->num_rows>0){
            $row=$query->row();
            // login successfull create session
            $this->session->set_userdata('USER_ID', $row->USER_ID);
            $this->session->set_userdata('USER_FULL_NAME', $row->USER_ENAME);

            return "success";
        }else{
            return "Invalid username and/or password.";
        }





    }
}

?>
```

Where,
PASSWORD_SALT, is a database field that contains 128 character long random(for each user) salt hashed using `hash` function.

The code works perfect if `USERNAME` is unique. But i m trying to think of the client who may ask that username should not be unique. If username is not unique it always select first row and all except one having same username will not be able to login even they provide valid username and password.

What will be better work around on this scenario?

**EDIT**

I know Putting `USERNAME` not unique is a bad idea. But in our country there are several websites where username is not unique (or in some case username is even  predictable). For example, I have an account in certain branch of bank whose branch code is `032`, and my name is John Smith, then the username to access their ebanking will be `032JOHNS`, there might be more than one John Smith in that branch finally having same username. And to login to their ebanking system i just need to provide this username and my password.

Thanks

Comment: Instead of storing static salt in database you can store it in config.And in this way you can check both username and password at a time. Something like this one $query=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM USER_INFOS WHERE STATUS='Y' AND USER_NNAME=? AND USER_PASSWORD=?",array($username,sha1($password).$this->config->item('static_salt'));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the username is not unique, then **what uniquely identifies the user**?

It has to be something the user provides at login, and it can't be a combination of username and password, because there's certainly no guarantee that two users won't pick the same password.

So if the username is not unique, then something else has to be unique (or be unique in combination with the username). For example, if they're doing some kind of multi-tenant by custom domains, then it would be the domain.

But you **can't have non-unique usernames and expect the password to determine the correct user**.

(Side note, well you *can*, but you *shouldn't* - I happen to be able to login into **two** different Amazon accounts using the **same** email address, but different passwords. I wonder what would happen if I changed one password to match the other, but I value my account too much to try it.)

Answer (score 1):

If you really MUST have non-unique usernames, you could loop over all users with the username and check password for each one of them, i.e. if 3 ppl have the username foobar, and the password check fails for the first, check for the second and so on.

(Note: I **STRONGLY recommend against this**. If username can't be unique, use email address as a unique identifier / for logging in).

Comment: I have thought of your solution, but logging in would be pretty slow if there are several 100s of users. Seems I have two options, either convince him to make username unique or use some other unique identifier to login. Please see my edit why i don't want username to be unique

Comment: Yep. Also if the first person misspells his password which just happens to be the next persons password, he gains access. Hence, the note.

Comment: @LoVeSmItH: Yes - either enforce uniqueness of username, or allow duplicate usernames, but use email for logging in.

Comment: yes, i understand these cases, how would those banks ebanking website working then, I just need to provide username and password to login there (please see my edit)

Comment: I'd wager these banking websites are not as safe as they should be. There's a pretty good chance they're looking through all John Smiths to find the one with whom the password matches. Just because banking websites are using it doesn't mean it is secure (you'd be surprised).

Comment: @LoVeSmItH Any place I've seen non-unique usernames (in banking) they actually are unique considering a secondary value (like state/province, account type, etc).

Comment: @TimLytle, well how they determine if logging form has just username field and password field? And upon suppliying valid username and password i m redirected to my account home page.

Comment: @LoVeSmItH Can't answer as to your case, like I said, whenever I've seen cases where there could be username collision, they're always using a secondary value *during* the login.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
$getsalt=$this->db->query("SELECT PASSWORD_SALT FROM USER_INFOS WHERE USER_NNAME=?",array($username))->row();
        $salt=$getsalt->PASSWORD_SALT;
        $password=sha1($salt.$password);

        $query=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM USER_INFOS WHERE STATUS='Y' AND USER_NNAME=? AND USER_PASSWORD=?",array($username,$password));
```

Use something like this this:

```
$query=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM USER_INFOS WHERE STATUS='Y' AND USER_NNAME=? AND USER_PASSWORD=SHA1(CONCAT(PASSWORD_SALT,?))",array($username,$password));
```

Comment: Might just be me, but I'm generally skeptical of sending unhashed passwords to the DB. CodeIgniter's Active Record will take care of sanitization, but in case someone somehow manages to sneak past a `OR 1 = 1;`, hashing it on the server adds a layer of protection.

Comment: `SHA1(CONCAT(PASSWORD_SALT,?))` - if someone will provide password as `OR 1 = 1` this value will be concatenated with salt and after this will go through `SHA1`. Don't think that `OR 1 = 1` will work here =)

Comment: @LoVeSmItH sys.dbms_crypto.hash(PASSWORD_SALT||?, sys.dbms_crypto.hash_sh1)

Comment: [maybe this will help you more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10469633/getting-different-encryption-results-between-c-net-and-oracle)